# Autolayout in ios6

Tags: ios

I am testing adding autolayout contraints to view programmatically. But it is hiding my view. I am writing code...

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 200.0, 600.0, 200.0)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

[self.view addSubview:testView];

[testView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(testView);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[testView(>=600)]-50-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Why this hiding my view?
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given it any constraints in the vertical direction, so a height of 0 points satisfies all the constraints you gave it. Autolayout likes to jump to 0 if you let it.